# Why is using a StreamWriter to write text to a string resulting in nothing being written?

Tags: c#, xml, stream

I have the following code

```
    public void SerializeToStream(Stream stream)
    {
        var xml = // Linq to xml code here

        // Write to the stream
        var writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
        writer.Write(xml.ToString());
    }
```

My `xml` object has the correct data, and I have verified that `xml.ToString()` shows everything correctly, but after `writer.Write(xml.ToString())` is called my incoming stream (regardless if it's a `FileStream` or `MemoryStream` still has nothing in it (and a length of zero).  No exceptions are thrown.  Why is this happening?

As a note, I cannot use `xml.WriteTo()` because the `XmlWriter` class adds extra stuff (the `<xml>` declaration tag) which I cannot have in my xml (Company policy for integration with another system I do not have control over).

Comment: Are you flushing, or autoflush is set to true?

Comment: it probably defaults the writing to the directory where he runs or launched the application..

Comment: @MystereMan:  The method signature provides the stream which is all a `StreamWriter` really needs...

Comment: @MystereMan what do you think `stream` is? possibly a file or a memory stream

Comment: It's writing to memory or to a file depending on some logic outside of this method, that's why it only takes a generic `stream`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're never flushing or closing the writer. (I'd normally suggest closing the writer, but that will also close the stream, which may not be what you want.) Simply add:

```
writer.Flush();
```

at the end of the method.

Note that you can remove the XML declaration from an `XDocument`, if you want. For example:

```
XDocument doc = new XDocument
    (new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"),
     new XElement("Root", "content"));
doc.Save(Console.Out); // Includes <? xml ... ?>
doc.Declaration = null;
doc.Save(Console.Out); // No declaration...
```

That should make it simpler:

```
public void SerializeToStream(Stream stream)
{
    var xml = // Linq to xml code here
    xml.Declaration = null;
    xml.Save(stream);
}
```

Comment: I couldn't get the `xml.Declaration = null` to work, as it still seemed to be written to when saving or writing the `XDocument`, but flushing the writer worked for my original question!

Comment: @KallDrexx: It's hard to comment on that as you haven't shown anything about your LINQ to XML code... if you could post a short but complete program demonstrating the problem as a second question, I could have a look if you like.

Comment: Opened http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8926784/why-is-my-xdocument-saving-the-declaration-when-i-dont-want-it-to with an example of it not working

Comment: @KallDrexx: Bizarrely enough, my own code is now giving me different results. Very odd.

Comment: at least I'm not the only crazy one :)

Answer (score 2):

I would bet it's because you're not closing the StreamWriter; flushing would likely work as well.

Wrapping it in a using block will take care of both for you.

```
...
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
    {
        writer.Write(xml.ToString());
    }
...
```

Note (from @Tigran):  `using`: this will affect also the stream object, which may be not a good choice in the function which accepts a stream like a parameter.

Comment: `using`: this will affect also the `stream` object, which may be not a good choice in the function which accepts  `stream` like a parameter.

Comment: I don't want to close the stream, as that will make it inaccessible after this method is run

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule, any time you are using a class that implements the IDisposable interface, you should really enclose it in a using block.  This ensures that the .Close() method is called before the object goes out of scope, freeing up resources.  I've also noticed that without a .Flush() at the end, the contents don't always get written out.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx

```
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
{
    writer.Write(xml.ToString());
    writer.Flush();
    // writer.Close() can be called here, but is automatically called at the end of the using block
}
```