# Why is my XDocument saving the declaration when I don't want it to?

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I have the following code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var stream = File.Create(@"C:\test.xml"))
        {
            var xml =
                new XElement("root",
                    new XElement("subelement1", "1"),
                    new XElement("subelement2", "2"));

            var doc = new XDocument(xml);
            doc.Declaration = null;
            doc.Save(stream);
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to get XML to save without the xml declaration, but even though I am nulling out the declaration of the `XDocument`, it is still being saved to the final XML.

This code is outputting:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <subelement1>1</subelement1>
  <subelement2>2</subelement2>
</root>
```

Comment: Why do you wish to save an XML document without the declaration? It is useful to include a declaration which specifies the encoding and the version of the XML document for consumers of the XML file.

Comment: Because this XML is being sent to some other in-company systems that apparently break if you have the xml declaration (and I have no control over those systems, it's another whole department)

Comment: that's fair enough :) I just wondered why

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Instead `XDocument.Save()` you can use `XmlWriter` with `XmlWriterSettings.OmitXmlDeclaration` set to `true`

```
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

XmlWriterSettings xws = new XmlWriterSettings();
xws.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;
xws.Indent = true;

using (var stream = File.Create(@"C:\test.xml"))
using (XmlWriter xw = XmlWriter.Create(stream, xws))
{
    var xml = new XElement(
        "root",
        new XElement("subelement1", "1"),
        new XElement("subelement2", "2"));

    xml.Save(xw);
}
```

Comment: I can't find this method, can you please give a link to `MSDN`?

Answer (score 9):

You *can* do this using `XmlWriter` with a custom [`XmlWriterSettings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwritersettings.aspx) (you'll need a using directive for `System.Xml`):

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var xml =
            new XElement("root",
                         new XElement("subelement1", "1"),
                         new XElement("subelement2", "2"));

        var doc = new XDocument(xml);
        var settings = new XmlWriterSettings
        {
            OmitXmlDeclaration = true
        };
        using (var stream = File.Create(@"test.xml"))
        {
            using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(stream, settings))
            {
                doc.Save(writer);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That's assuming you want to specify the `Stream` - you can also create an `XmlWriter` from the filename:

```
using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create("test.xml", settings))
{
    doc.Save(writer);
}
```

(If you don't need the `XDocument` for anything else, you can just call `Save` on the root element, of course, in the same way.)

Comment: EDIT: if you DO NOT use Jon's code then it still adds the declaration as the `XDocument.Save` method calls the `XNode.GetXmlWriterSettings` method, which then returns a new `XmlWriterSettings` object, which has `OmitXmlDeclaration` set to false by default

Comment: @JamesShuttler: The code above does *not* write the declaration for me. Did you try it and find that it did?

Comment: Why do you build the `XML` body in `XElement` and then insert it to `XDocument`. Instead of build the whole `XML` with `XDocument`?

Comment: @gdoron: That's what the OP's code does. I've *only* changed the saving part.

Comment: @JonSkeet sorry I wasn't clear, your code doesn't write the XML declaration, that's correct. You said you weren't sure why it still added the declaration even though it had been explicitly removed in the poster's code. I was explaining why it is still added if you do not use the code that you have provided

Comment: @JamesShuttler: Ah, right. That makes sense. Will just remove that bit to start with.

Comment: and for clarification, I only put it into the XDocument since that's where the `.Declaration` property resides, and I thought I would have to use an `XDocument` root to get the declaration not to show.