# How to remove the XML declaration when using LINQ to XML?

Tags: c#, xml, linq

i have a LINQ query like this, i need to remove the XML Declaration tag which is getting added automatically.

```
var cubbingmessagexml = new XDocument(
                        new XElement("MESSAGE", new XAttribute("ID", "CUB"),
                        new XElement("RECORD", new XAttribute("STORENO", cubing.StoreID),
                                                new XAttribute("TPNB", cubing.ProductCode),
                                                new XAttribute("QUANTITY", cubing.Quantity),
                                                new XAttribute("CUBINGTIME", cubing.CubingDateTime.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss")),
                                                new XAttribute("SHELFFACING", cubing.ShelfFacing)
                                      )));



                    xml = cubbingmessagexml.ToString();
```

pls help

I dont want to save the XML file, just need to return the XML as a string

Comment: What are you saving to? A file? A TextWriter?

Comment: i am not saving the XML, this is a logic written inside a method which will return string

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8926784/why-is-my-xdocument-saving-the-declaration-when-i-dont-want-it-to. I don't think there is a way with `ToString`.

Comment: What .NET version are you in, out of interest? ToString doesn't show the declaration for me on .NET 4.5...

Comment: can't you just delete it from the string and save it as a 'File'?

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance, i am on .NET 4.0

Comment: @LiranElisha, thanks but i dont want save , but return the xml as string

Comment: That code doesn't show a declaration in .NET 4.0 for me...

Comment: That code doesn't show a declaration in .NET 3.5 for me... i think we need more information

Comment: Can't reproduce either. What's the value of the variable xml if you check it in the debugger?

Comment: @Fung, it will not have the declaration tag

Comment: @Pradeep Rao Problem solved then?

Comment: @Fung, No still have problem

Comment: Does any one have a suggestion

Comment: Please clarify in simple English -- do you **want** the XML declaration and you are **not** getting it? Or do you **not want** the XML declaration and you **are** getting it?

Comment: i dont need the XML Declaration

Comment: So now the question is: what do you do with the value in the `xml` variable, which is not in the code you've posted.

Answer (score 2):

If you are referring the xml version and stuff at the top, there is an xml writer setting to turn that off.

```
var writerSettings = new XmlWriterSettings();
writerSettings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;

using (var buffer = new StringWriter())
using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(buffer, writerSettings))
{
    cubbingmessagexml.Save(writer);
    writer.Flush();
    string result = buffer.ToString();
}
```

Comment: hi HaoYuan, as i have mentioned in the comment i dont want to save the XML file, just need to return the XML as a string, so your suggestion above will not workout

Comment: @PradeepRao Yes it will; see revised answer. HaoYuan mentioned you'd have to use a StringWriter.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Skip the `XDocument`:</strike>

```
var cubbingmessagexml = 
    new XElement("MESSAGE", new XAttribute("ID", "CUB"),
        new XElement("RECORD", 
            new XAttribute("STORENO", cubing.StoreID),
            new XAttribute("TPNB", cubing.ProductCode),
            new XAttribute("QUANTITY", cubing.Quantity),
            new XAttribute("CUBINGTIME", cubing.CubingDateTime.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss")),
            new XAttribute("SHELFFACING", cubing.ShelfFacing)
        )
    );

xml = cubbingmessagexml.ToString();
```

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387063.aspx):

> Note that you only have to create XDocument objects if you require the specific functionality provided by the XDocument class. In many circumstances, you can work directly with XElement. Working directly with XElement is a simpler programming model.

and

> As previously mentioned, the XElement class is the main class in the LINQ to XML programming interface. In many cases, your application will not require that you create a document. By using the XElement class, you can create an XML tree, add other XML trees to it, modify the XML tree, and save it.

Even with `XDocument` the declaration is not displayed.

Comment: hi Zev Spitz, thanks for answering, but even with XDocument in the code i was not getting the XML declaration part in the variable "xml", i am not sure if removing this would add any value

Comment: I'm confused. Do you want the XML declaration, or not?

Comment: i need to remove that, what i meant in the above comment was while trying to debug the code i added a watch of the variable "xml" in the above code(last line of the code) and it never had a declaration tag

Comment: @PradeepRao You should keep tracing your code, find the line where you get the xml string with XML declaration, and post it in your question. Otherwise we won't be able to answer since none of us can reproduce the problem from the code you provided.